Flutter/Supabase real time changes using current timestamp comparison
I’m trying to build a real time stream of database records back to my Flutter app based upon a test of a timestamp field called ‘required_by’ against the current system timestamp.
I want to receive a list of records where the ‘required_by’ field value is greater than the system timestamp.
How can I set this up?


Initialize Supabase in your Flutter app. Check on the supabase website on how to do this. it should be quite straightforward
Fetch initial data where required_by is in the future. Code below.
Subscribe to real-time changes (inserts and updates) on the tasks
table. Code below
Filter incoming records on the client-side based on the required_by
timestamp. Code below
Ensure time synchronization by using server-side timestamps. Code below

// real_time_stream_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

class RealTimeStreamScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RealTimeStreamScreenState createState() => _RealTimeStreamScreenState();
}

class _RealTimeStreamScreenState extends State<RealTimeStreamScreen> {
  final SupabaseClient supabase = Supabase.instance.client;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> tasks = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchInitialData();
    subscribeToChanges();
  }

  // Fetch initial records where required_by > now
  Future<void> fetchInitialData() async {
    final response = await supabase
        .from('tasks')
        .select()
        .gt('required_by', DateTime.now().toIso8601String())
        .order('required_by', ascending: true)
        .execute();

    if (response.error == null) {
      setState(() {
        tasks = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(response.data);
      });
    } else {
      // Handle error
      print('Error fetching data: ${response.error!.message}');
    }
  }

  // Subscribe to real-time inserts and updates
  void subscribeToChanges() {
    supabase
        .from('tasks')
        .on(SupabaseEventTypes.insert, (payload) {
      handleNewOrUpdatedRecord(payload.newRecord);
    })
        .on(SupabaseEventTypes.update, (payload) {
      handleNewOrUpdatedRecord(payload.newRecord);
    })
        .subscribe((status) {
      if (status == RealtimeSubscriptionStatus.connected) {
        print('Connected to real-time');
      }
    });
  }

  // Handle incoming records
  void handleNewOrUpdatedRecord(Map<String, dynamic> record) {
    DateTime requiredBy = DateTime.parse(record['required_by']);
    if (requiredBy.isAfter(DateTime.now())) {
      setState(() {
        // Check if the record already exists
        int index = tasks.indexWhere((t) => t['id'] == record['id']);
        if (index >= 0) {
          tasks[index] = record;
        } else {
          tasks.add(record);
          tasks.sort((a, b) =>
              DateTime.parse(a['required_by'])
                  .compareTo(DateTime.parse(b['required_by'])));
        }
      });
    } else {
      // Optionally remove records that no longer meet the criteria
      setState(() {
        tasks.removeWhere((t) => t['id'] == record['id']);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    supabase.removeAllSubscriptions();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Upcoming Tasks'),
        ),
        body: tasks.isEmpty
            ? Center(child: Text('No upcoming tasks.'))
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: tasks.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var task = tasks[index];
                  DateTime requiredBy = DateTime.parse(task['required_by']);
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(task['title'] ?? 'No Title'),
                    subtitle: Text('Required by: ${requiredBy.toLocal()}'),
                  );
                },
              ));
  }
}


Use Server Timestamps when inserting or updating records

for Example
Future<void> addTask(String title, DateTime requiredBy) async {
  final response = await supabase.from('tasks').insert({
    'title': title,
    'required_by': requiredBy.toIso8601String(),
    // Other fields...
  }).execute();

  if (response.error != null) {
    print('Error adding task: ${response.error!.message}');
  }
}


Handle Time Zones: Ensure that both client and server handle time
zones consistently, preferably using UTC.
Optimize Queries: Index the required_by column in your Supabase
database for faster queries.
Error Handling: Implement comprehensive error handling for network
issues and subscription errors.


Thanks for the response.  But this does not handle a situation where the app has been running for a long time, and where an existing record which had a 'required_by' field value was before the system time when the app started,  as time progresses forward, the same record will at some point be after the system time stamp.    I can't see anyway around this other than polling the same query at a fixed interval. Suggestions?
